# typedef declaration syntax understanding?

Tags: c++

I ran into this code and don't know what it does. Can you decipher it?

```
typedef std::map<std::string, bool (Foo::*)()> x_t;
```

The part I don't understand is the value of the map. I'm surprised its valid c++ syntax.

Thanks.

Comment: Where does 'regex' come into the question? (For what's worth, I don't think you can parse C++ type declarations with regex expressions, but have never really tried)

Comment: @David Your right. I was incorrectly reading the pointer as meaning all functions in a particular namespace. Sorry.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`bool (Foo::*)()` is a pointer to member function of `Foo` that takes no arguments and returns `bool`. So `x_t` is probably used to map names of member functions to the actual members.

Comment: Side note on how to use such a pointer, for potential readers: a plain pointer to function `bool (*pf)() = &bar;` can be used as `(*pf)()` or simply `pf()` (here equivalent to `bar()` but with an added indirection); a pointer to member function `bool (Foo::*pmf)() = &Foo::baz;` requires an object of the class [or a pointer] to be called on with the operator `.*` [or `->*`]: `Foo x;` and `(x.*pmf)()` (parentheses needed) [or `Foo* px = &x;` and `(px->*pmf)()`] (here equivalent to `x.baz()` [or `px->baz()`] but with an added indirection).

Answer (score 1):

`x_t` is a `map` from a `string` to a pointer-to-member-function-of-`Foo` returning `bool`.

You can read C++ declarations backwards, or in some cases, inside out.  The value of the map is read from the `*` as a `Foo` member function returning `bool`, the key of the map is clearly a `string`, and `x_t` is a type alias for a map from key to value.